# Pricing Compound Options using QuantLib

Tags: programming, quantlib

I am trying to price Compound Options using `QuantLib` on Python. I've looked around but am unable to find any sample code. I believe that the CompoundOption Class should be used?

https://rkapl123.github.io/QLAnnotatedSource/dc/dae/class_quant_lib_1_1_compound_option.html

If you know of any sample code or if you know how to use `QuantLib` to price compound options, could you please assist. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Looking for the same! No luck yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the `CompoundOption` class has been exported to the python module

If you try:

```
import QuantLib as ql
ql.CompoundOption()
```

You will get an error:

`AttributeError: module 'QuantLib' has no attribute 'CompoundOption'`